# list / get variables from flash ( .swf)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flash

is possible to get variable from flash to javascript, php...

for example in flash i have :

```
var myVar = 25;
```

how i can get variable ( myVar ) from flash to javascript ( jquery, ajax or php.. )
smoething like

```
myJsVar = myVar; ( from flash )
```

or how to list all variables from flash to javascript ( jquery , ajax or php ), and how to set new variables to flash using javascript ( jquery , ajax or other );

Comment: Use ExternalInterface.  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html lots of examples if you google it.